# VBA- WorkSheetFunction.SumIF - Defining Arguments

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I ve been reading about Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs grammar but I still don t get it.

My question:
I am looking for the content of a cell or some word "Example" into a row. Then what I need is to sum all the values of another row when they match that word,"Example".
Here s my code

```
Sub sumasi()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsD As Worksheet
Dim Arg1 As Range
Dim Arg2 As Range
Dim Arg3 As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsD = wb.Worksheets("Data")

    Set Arg1 = wsD.Range("A1:RH1") 'where to find
    Set Arg2 = wsD.Range("SG3") 'what to find
    Set Arg3 = wsD.Range("AK4:RH4") 'what to sum

    wsD.Range("SG4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)


End Sub
```

My code doesn t work...coud you help me?
Thanks! 
(I don t want to write the Formula on the cell, I want to write directly the value because I am avoiding using formulas due to Excel weight)
Thanks again

Cheers

Comment: Switch `arg1` and `arg3` around, or use `SumIf` rather than `SumIfs`.

Comment: Your `Arg1` and `Arg3` will need to be the same shape - at the moment `Arg1` is 1 row x 476 columns but `Arg3` is 1 row x 440 columns.  And I believe you should be passing `(Arg3, Arg1, Arg2)` based on the descriptions in your comments.  And if that isn't the issue, please expand on "My code doesn't work" - that is a **terrible** problem description.

Comment: Is there a reason *NOT* to use `wsD.Range("SG4").Formula = "=SUMIF(...)"` ?

Comment: Try reading the Microsoft site for the function - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b It mentions very well what the first 3 arguments are.

Comment: HI! Thank s for your comments.
I)
I don t want to write the formule because it takes memory and time. At the end it will be lots of formulas and thus excel gets slow.
II)
I tried changing the arguments and making them also with the same lenght. The code works now, but it doesn t sum the right values and gives me "0"

Comment: Using Formula this is what I need:
=(SUMIFS(AK4:RH4;$AK$1:$RH$1;"Example"))

Comment: Check your `arg` ranges.  If that doesn't help, upload a sample worksheet that demonstrates the problem.  Upload this to some sharing site (eg: OneDrive, DropBox) and post a link here.

Comment: Don't know if you updated it in your code, but the code above still shows `Set Arg1 = wsD.Range("A1:RH1")` when it should be `Set Arg1 = wsD.Range("AK1:RH1")`

Comment: It should be `=SUMIFS(Arg3, Arg1, Arg2)`.  And your `Arg1` should also change to `AK1:RH1` to make both sum range and criteria range the same size.  Also, you may want to try the formula on the spreadsheet first to see if it works or not before trying on VBA.